# What is the significance of "ProjectTemplate.csproj" and "ProjectTemplate1.vstemplate" in the proejct template?

Tags: .net, templates

The title is the question. I am curious to know about the importance of those.As per my understanding the .csproject contains the entries that will be compiled(e.g. classes,references)

```
<ItemGroup>
        <Reference Include="System"/>
        $if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 3.5)
        <Reference Include="System.Core"/>
        <Reference Include="System.Xml.Linq"/>
        <Reference Include="System.Data.DataSetExtensions"/>
        $endif$
        $if$ ($targetframeworkversion$ >= 4.0)
        <Reference Include="Microsoft.CSharp"/>
        $endif$
        <Reference Include="System.Data"/>
        <Reference Include="System.Xml"/>
    </ItemGroup>
    <ItemGroup>
        <Compile Include="Class1.cs" />

        <Compile Include="Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>
```

and the ProjectTemplate1.vstemplate is the link for those.Is this is correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

.vstemplate defines the project template. It will typically include a templated definition of a .csproj (or several) that will be created when you instantiate a project from that template.

So, in the example you gave, your .vstemplate would probably contain something like

```
<VSTemplate Type="Project" Version="3.0.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/vstemplate/2005">
    <TemplateContent>
        <Project File="ProjectTemplate.csproj">
            <ProjectItem>Class1.cs</ProjectItem>
            <ProjectItem>Properties\AssemblyInfo.cs</ProjectItem>
        </Project>
    </TemplateContent>
</VSTemplate>
```